# Is it possible to convert a sympy expression to a pyomo expression?

Tags: python, sympy, pyomo

I'm currently using sympy to parse a string equation and replace the variables with either values or Pyomo variables:

```
model = pe.ConcreteModel()
model.flow = pe.Var()

DEMAND = 100

equation = sympify('10 * DEMAND * FLOW', evaluate=False)

updated_equation = equation.subs('DEMAND', DEMAND).subs('FLOW', model.flow)
```

Does anyone know if it is then possible to convert this to a linear expression I can use in a Pyomo model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if you look in `pyomo.core.expr.sympy_tools`, there are two methods:

- `sympyify_expression(expr)` will take a Pyomo expression and return a sympy expression, with all Pyomo Var objects replaced by sympy real Symbols, along with a `PyomoSympyBimap` object that maps the Pyomo Var objects to the corresponding sympy Symbol objects
- `sympy2pyomo_expression(expr, object_map)` will take a sympy expression (containing sympy Symbols), along with the `PyomoSymbolBimap` that relates the Symbols to Pyomo components and will return a native Pyomo expression.

What you are asking for is something slightly different: You are starting with a sympy expression that already contains Pyomo objects. You should be able to adapt the `Sympy2PyomoVisitor` class to work for your specific use case (you should only need to reimplement the `beforeChild` method to allow for the presence of Pyomo components)